# How to set a condition that my function continues if the values are all true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start a new function when all `.numbers` are `true`. If one is `false` i want to stop the function after he found all wrong. `.numbers` is a column in my table. I want to check if they are correct. I don't know how to achieve that. Can you help me out?

```js
$("#clickit").click(function() {
  $(".numbers").filter(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text()) === false) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("out1");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What type of element is `.numbers`? Also you say you want to check them for true/false, yet you're using `$.isNumeric'...?

Comment: its a column of my table
every td has the class numbers

Comment: There is no 'column' in HTML. Do you mean it's a `td` cell, or is it an `input` within the cell? My point here is that we need a lot more, clearer, detail to be able to help you debug the problem

Comment: okay sorry i try to be clearer
yeah its only a td cell

Comment: I just want to check out if all tds have no wrong inputs .
I check if they are numeric and if they are all true i want to send an ajax.
if not i want to color the wrong one.

Comment: Can you share a minimal html ?

Comment: @pedram think this can be inferred: `<table><tr><td class='numbers'>abc</td><tr></table>` (only by following the above comments though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this, here's one option:

- find all invalid numbers and give them a class
- check if there are any elements with that class

this can be combined, but for simplicity, treat them as two distinct checks:

```
$(".numbers").each(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("notvalid", !$.isNumeric($(this).text()));
});

if ($(".numbers.notvalid").length === 0)
  // ok to continue
```

Demonstration snippet:

```js
$(".numbers").each(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("notvalid", !$.isNumeric($(this).text()));
});


// Example usage
if ($(".numbers.notvalid").length === 0)
    $("#out").text("all pass");
else 
    $("#out").text("not all passed");
```

```css
.notvalid { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Line1</td><td class='numbers'>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>Line2</td><td class='numbers'>abc</td></tr>
<tr><td>Line3</td><td class='numbers'>456</td></tr>
<tr><td>Line4</td><td class='numbers'>789</td></tr>
<table>
<hr/>
<div id="out"></div>
```

---

To update your attempt, `.filter` can be used to return a filtered list by returning true (keep in the list) / false (remove from the list).  As you don't want to have to check how many were there to compare, you can return how many failed (similar to above), giving:

```
$("#clickit").click(function() {
  if ($(".numbers").filter(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text()) === false) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      return true;
    } else {
      // reset the "red" ones - this is easier with add/remove class
      $(this).css("background-color", "white");
      return false;
    }
  })).length === 0) {
    // none have an error, ok to continue
  }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense.
Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: "an error" - what error?  `$(select).length` would never throw a missing function error, but there might be an error in the selector, so depends on what the error is.  Updated with a demonstration snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag for this:

```
$("#clickit").click(function() {
  let flag = 0;
  $(".numbers").filter(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).text()) === false) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      flag++;
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", ""); // Remove the css as well.
    }
  });
  if (flag) {
    //error handling.
  } else {
    //continue your logic
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, you can `count` number of invalid `text`, if it's equal to zero, that means all your `text` are `true`

```js
$("#clickit").click(function() {
  invalid = 0;
  $(".numbers").filter(function() {
    if (!$.isNumeric($(this).text())) {
      invalid++;
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (invalid === 0) {
    alert('all set!')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="numbers">2</td>
      <td class="numbers">1</td>
      <td class="numbers">1</td>
      <td class="numbers">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="clickit">Check</button>
```